# How do I use CanCan to classify customers after they signed in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

The below is my class Ability. It means if you are admin you can do everything, else you just can read. But i don't know how to classify customers after they signed in? If you have any suggestion pls help me!

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, :all
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to write a specific question, that can be answered.

Answer (score 1):

you can write a method in ApplicationController like:

```
def require_admin
 current_user.admin?
end
```

then in your desired controller, you can use

```
before_action :require_admin, except: :show
```

I guess I gave you an idea and you should improvise it.

Comment: so how can i define an user to be admin?

Comment: add a boolean column in you user table called admin.